# Merging 2 dataframes by date column (no look-ahead bias)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am trying to create a python function that takes in 2 dataframes (dfA, dfB) and merges them based on their date column. When merging, B looks for the nearest date in A that is either equal to or comes before the given date. This is to prevent the data in dfAB from looking into the future (which is why dfAB.iloc[4]['date'] = 1/4/21 and not 1/9/21)

dfA

```
      date  i
0   1/1/21  0
1   1/3/21  0
2   1/4/21  0
3  1/10/21  0
```

dfB

```
     date  j  k
0  1/1/21  0  0
1  1/2/21  0  0
2  1/3/21  0  0
3  1/9/21  0  0
4  1/12/21 0  0
```

dfAB (note that for each row of dfB, there is a row of dfAB)

```
     date  j  k  i
0  1/1/21  0  0  0
1  1/1/21  0  0  0
2  1/3/21  0  0  0
3  1/4/21  0  0  0
4  1/10/21 0  0  0
```

The values in columns i, j, k are just arbitrary values

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: The grain of your result is somewhat confusing.  So for each row of B there should be a row of AB but with the date marched back to match some date in A?  Also I think what you want would be more interpretable if you put different numbers in the rows of i, j, and k so we could see better how the data is being matched up.  That being said, this sounds like it should be doable with `pd.merge_asof`, but it looks like you're doing some additional contortions.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this we can use `pd.merge_asof` and a bit of trickery to push the `date` column from `dfB` back to the `date` column from `dfA`

```
# a.csv
date  i
1/1/21  0
1/3/21  0
1/4/21  0
1/10/21  0
```

```
# b.csv
date  j  k
1/1/21  0  0
1/2/21  0  0
1/3/21  0  0
1/9/21  0  0
1/12/21 0  0
```

```
# merge_ab.py
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.read_csv(
    'a.csv',
    delim_whitespace=True,
    parse_dates=['date'],
    dayfirst=True,
)

dfB = pd.read_csv(
    'b.csv',
    delim_whitespace=True,
    parse_dates=['date'],
    dayfirst=True,
)

dfA['new_date'] = dfA['date']
dfAB = pd.merge_asof(dfB, dfA, on='date', direction='backward')
dfAB['date'] = dfAB['new_date']
dfAB = dfAB.drop(columns=['new_date'])

print(dfAB)
#         date  j  k  i
# 0 2021-01-01  0  0  0
# 1 2021-01-01  0  0  0
# 2 2021-03-01  0  0  0
# 3 2021-04-01  0  0  0
# 4 2021-10-01  0  0  0
```

Here `pd.merge_asof` is doing the heavy lifting.  We are merge the rows of `dfB` *backwards*`with the rows of`dfA`.  This should make it so the data in any row of` dfAB`only has data from equal to or before the corresponding row in`dfB`.  We do a little song and dance to copy the` date`column in`dfA`and then copy that over to the`date`column in`dfAB` to get the desired output.

It's not 100% clear to me that you want `direction='backward'` since all your sample data is `0`, but if it doesn't look right you can always switch to `direction='forward'`.